# How to use URI templates within a Spring MVC Interceptor?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller uri hierarchy similar to the example below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="company/{id}")
public abstract class BaseCompanyController 
{
  // variety of helper methods, protected autowired objects 
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "company/{id}/documents")
public class DocumentsController extends BaseCompanyController
{
  // document controller methods 
   @RequestMapping(value="something",.... etc)
   public void doSomething(){}
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "company/{id}/financials")
public class FinancialsController extends BaseCompanyController
{
  // financials controllers methods 
}
```

What I want to do is to define some code to execute before any handler method in any child controllers. For example I would like to run some code before the doSomething method is called on the DocumentsController. The things I want to do are unique for a specific URI hierarchy.

If I use an interceptor to execute before the handler methods how do I extract the URI parameters from the URI such as the company id from /company/{id}? I really don't want to pares the URL's by hand?

Can an interceptor be narrowed down with a URI such as /company/{id} do interceptor mappings understand URI templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interceptors only for certain URIs using `<mvc:mapping/>` and `path` attribute for each one:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/company/*/documents" />
        <bean class="com.mypackage.DocumentsInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors).